# Find distance between all pairs of pixels in an image

Tags: python, performance, numpy, linear-algebra

#### Question

I have a `numpy.array` of shape `(H, W)`, storing pixel intensities of an image. I want to generate a new array of shape `(H, W, H, W)`, which stores the Euclidean distance between each pair of pixels in the image (the "spatial" distance between the pixels; not the difference in their intensities).

#### Solution attempt

The following method does exactly what I want, but very slowly. I'm looking for a fast way to do this.

```
d = numpy.zeros((H, W, H, W)) # array to store distances.
for x1 in range(H):
    for y1 in range(W):
        for x2 in range(H):
            for y2 in range(W):
                d[x1, y1, x2, y2] = numpy.sqrt( (x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2 )
```

#### Extra details

Here are more details for my problem. A solution to the simpler problem above would probably be enough for me to figure out the rest.

- In my case, the image is actually a 3D medical image (i.e. a `numpy.array` of shape `(H, W, D)`).
- The 3D pixels might not be cubic (e.g. each pixel might represent a volume of 1mm x 2mm x 3mm).

Comment: So you are trying to compute the distances between **the coordinates of the pixels**, not the pixels' intensity themselves?

Comment: @QuangHoang yes, trying to find distances between **the coordinates of the pixels**.

Comment: The pixels themselves could be of different volumes?

Comment: @Jensun It is a 3D medical image, where each 3D pixel ("voxel") represents a little volume. The volumes are rectangular prisms, but they might not be cubic. All of the voxels have the same shape.

Comment: Must the distances be computed between the voxel centroids?

Comment: @Jensun yes, between the centroids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can setup open grids with `1D` ranged arrays using `np.ogrid`, which could be operated upon in the same iterator notation for a vectorized solution and this will leverage [`broadcasting`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) for the perf. boost :

```
X1,Y1,X2,Y2 = np.ogrid[:H,:W,:H,:W]
d_out = numpy.sqrt( (X2-X1)**2 + (Y2-Y1)**2 )
```

To save on two open grids :

```
X,Y = np.ogrid[:H,:W]
d_out = numpy.sqrt( (X[:,:,None,None]-X)**2 + (Y[:,:,None,None]-Y)**2 )
```

If we are working with large arrays, consider using `numexpr` for further boost :

```
import numexpr as ne

d_out = ne.evaluate('sqrt( (X2-X1)**2 + (Y2-Y1)**2 )')
```

Comment: I tried these and they all seem to work, and are faster than my loop method. I have a bigger problem in that the image is too large to realistically do this calculation or store the result - e.g. a 100x100x100 image would have ~10^6 pixels and ~10^12 pairs of pixels. I marked your answer as accepted because I think it answers the question as I asked it.